# RSA encryption using multiplication

Tags: rsa

Generally in RSA we encrypt as $m^e \pmod n$. Will RSA work if we replace the power by normal multiplication? $E = (m \times e) \mod n$  and decryption as $c \times d \mod n$. What will be $d$ disadvantage if it works ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Suppose an RSA public key is still $(e, N)$ and the private key is still $d$. We have $Enc = (m*e) \text{ mod } N$ and $Dec = (c*d) \text{ mod } N$. The correctness of the scheme depends on the fact that $Dec(Enc(m)) = (m*e*d) \text{ mod } N = m \text{ mod } N$. This implies $e*d = 1 \text{ mod } N$. It is thus trivial to compute the private key given only the public key (i.e. compute $d = e^{-1} \text{ mod } N$). Hence this scheme is completely broken.

Note that this scheme only works if $e$ and $N$ are coprime otherwise no $d$ such that $e*d = 1 \text{ mod } N$ exists.

Answer (score 9):

***Assumption:*** $e$ and $d$ are prime with $N$.

If we use the multiplication instead of the power. We have $d \equiv e^{-1} \pmod N$ :

\begin{align}c \times d &= m &\mod N\\
m \times e \times d &= m &\mod N\\
e \times d &= 1 &\mod N
\end{align}
(It has to work for any $m$ so we can suppose $m$ prime).

$e$ and $N$ are publicly known, to compute $d$ the inverse of $e$, you just need the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) : 
$e$ is prime with $N$, therefore there exists $u, v$ such as 
$$e \times u + N \times v = 1$$
by [Bezout's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_theorem)
$$e \times u = 1 \pmod N$$
Therefore $u = d = e^{-1}$ which is easily computed.